# Creating my own makefile [Error 255]

Tags: gcc, makefile, g++

I have been enjoying the luxury of coding with an IDE that writes my makefile's for me, Iv decided that I have been 'short cutting' for far to long, so I have read a few manuals and watched a few videos on makefiles and have a makefile semi-done, the only trouble that I'm having is I'm not sure how to link libraries.

```
CPPS := $(shell ls src/*cpp)
TEMP := $(subst src/,obj/,$(CPPS))
OBJS := $(subst .cpp,.o,$(TEMP))
HEADERS := $(shell ls inc/*.h)
EXEC := bin/testfile

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC) : $(OBJS) $(HEADERS)
g++ -I inc/ $(OBJS) -o $(EXEC) -lSDL -lGLU
$(EXEC)

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
g++ -Wall -I inc/ -c $< -o $@
```

ps: just incase I am saying the wrong thing when I say 'Library flags' I mean `-lSDL -lGLU` etc...

Wherever I put them they dont seem to work.

This is the error I get when I insert the lib flags,
`make: *** [bin/testfile] Error 255`

> The Error 255 is produced by make as a result of its command shell not being able to find a command for a particular rule.

If i dont include them I get standard 'undefined' messages.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: I dont see any `-l` flags in the snippet you've pasted! Its difficult to follow things like "10th line" "last line"

Comment: Can you also tell us what errors you are facing when you say "dont seem to work"?

Comment: @PavanManjunath `make: *** [bin/testfile] Error 255`

Comment: There might be some tabulation characters missing (as the first character of command lines) in your `Makefile`

Comment: A good tool to debug `Makefile` is `remake`; you could invoke it as `remake -x -d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run your executable after you have built it?

It that case the problem is that you don't have your current directory on the PATH; so make can't find `$(EXEC)`.

You should probably just do `./$(EXEC)` to run it directly.

And you should move executing the program to a different (`PHONY`) target, so that you can do just the build step on its own, and run when `$(EXEC)` doesn't need to be built.

(I'm assuming the lack of tabs is just stackoverflow formatting, as otherwise `make` would be complaining).

Comment: Your bang on the money there! thanks, am I linking the libraries correctly? my prog doesn't seem to be executing, but no error displays. Yet when built using an IDE it works just fine...

Comment: @Elgoog I'm afraid you haven't provided enough information; Have you made the changes I suggested? I'd removing executing the program from your Makefile, and running it directly - then it's easier to see what's going on.