# Error 255 when try to create .exe using dev-C++

Tags: c++, window, dev-c++

Today i got the most generic compile error for Dev-C++ ever

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "C:\projects\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...

make.exe -f "C:\projects\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -c test.cpp -o test.o -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include"  -I"C:/SDL-1.2.15/include"   

make.exe: *** [test.o] Error 255

Execution terminated
```

and that's it. I googled around online but usually you can see some other type of errors follow it within the compile log but no in my case. Anyone help. I am running this on window 8

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086607/creating-my-own-makefile-error-255 helpful?

Comment: @KarthikT I am using window 8 I think there is something in 8 that is missing which cause the error. Tried again on window 7 and it works.

Comment: Considering the copy of GCC that DevCPP bundles was out of date in the XP days, I'm not surprised it doesn't like 8 out of the box. You should probably update to the latest version of MinGW instead of using the one bundled with DevCPP.

Answer (score 3):

Please update your IDE to the following version, which fixes an immense list of bugs, ships with GCC 4.6.1 or 4.7.0, and is fully portable: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

That would be the number one fix to try and fix this problem regarding the automatically generated makefile. Chances are the updated version will fix your makefile problems.

You could also open up the auto generated makefile yourself and:

- Go to Project >> Project Options >> Makefile and tick "use custom makefile".
- Try to fix the makefile manually.
- ???
- Rebuild.
- Profit.

If this option was previously left unticked, you are sure either the old Dev-C++ made an error creating the makefile or the bundled compiler got broken for some reason.